# SSRS 2005 Horizontal Matrix with dynamic rows

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a question regarding SSRS, the Matrix control and generating dynamic rows.

I currently have a dataset that gives a list of values broken down by week:

```
 Week | Value1| Value2 | Value3
 W1   | 1     | 2      | 3
 W2   | 4     | 5      | 6
```

Which I display on a week-by-week breakdown on a report using a matrix control? Here the row headings static but the column headings are dynamically added from the dataset:

```
         | W1    | W2
 Value1  | 1     | 4
 Value2  | 2     | 5
 Value3  | 3     | 6
```

This part is fine however I now need to add another dimension as the final report needs to be split by a couple of variables. The new dataset will be something like this

```
 Week | VariableA | VariableB | Value1| Value2 | Value3
 W1   | ResultA   | Result1   | 1     | 1      | 1 
 W1   | ResultB   | Result1   | 0     | 1      | 1 
 W1   | ResultA   | Result2   | 0     | 0      | 1 
 W2   | ResultA   | Result1   | 1     | 2      | 5 
 W2   | ResultA   | Result2   | 3     | 3      | 1
```

And I need to generate a report like so:

```
                | W1    | W2
 Value1 ResultA | 1     | 4
 Value1 ResultB | 0     | 0
 Value1 Result1 | 1     | 1
 Value1 Result2 | 0     | 3
```

Is it possible to generate dynamic rows in this way whilst I am also generating dynamic columns? I do not know what the values for the variables are going to be.

Thanks in advance and leave a comment if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the result using SQL by applying the UNPIVOT and the PIVOT functions.  The UNPIVOT will be applied twice, the first time to convert the multiple columns of `value1`, `value2` into rows and then the second implementation will convert the `variablea`/`variableb` columns to rows.

The basic syntax will be:

```
select week, 
  col + ' ' + varcol1, value
from table1
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (value1, value2, value3)
) u
unpivot
(
  var
  for c in (variablea, variableb)
) u1;
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c56ae/6). This gives a result similar to:

```
| WEEK |           COL1 | VALUE |
---------------------------------
|   W1 | Value1 ResultA |     1 |
|   W1 | Value1 Result1 |     1 |
|   W1 | Value2 ResultA |     1 |
|   W1 | Value2 Result1 |     1 |
|   W1 | Value3 ResultA |     1 |
|   W1 | Value3 Result1 |     1 |
|   W1 | Value1 ResultB |     0 |
```

Then you can apply the PIVOT function to convert the `W1` and `W2` values into columns:

```
select col1, W1, W2
from
(
  select week, 
    col + ' ' + var col1, value
  from table1
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (value1, value2, value3)
  ) u
  unpivot
  (
    var
    for c in (variablea, variableb)
  ) u1
) d
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for week in (W1, W2)
) p;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c56ae/7). This converts the data to the result:

```
|           COL1 | W1 |     W2 |
--------------------------------
| Value1 Result1 |  1 |      1 |
| Value1 Result2 |  0 |      3 |
| Value1 ResultA |  1 |      4 |
| Value1 ResultB |  0 | (null) |
| Value2 Result1 |  2 |      2 |
| Value2 Result2 |  0 |      3 |
| Value2 ResultA |  1 |      5 |
| Value2 ResultB |  1 | (null) |
| Value3 Result1 |  2 |      5 |
| Value3 Result2 |  1 |      1 |
| Value3 ResultA |  2 |      6 |
| Value3 ResultB |  1 | (null) |
```

This could be converted to dynamic SQL which would need to be placed in a stored procedure.

Comment: @MacsDickinson If you want a dynamic sql version - then you could use something similar to this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4715/1